# Convert columns to comma separated list if 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to convert some columns containing either 1 or 0 to a comma separated list with its column names.

More specific, with an example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), A = c("0", "1", "1", "0"), B = c("1", "1", "0", "0"), C = c("0", "0", "1", "1"))
```

If columns A, B and C are equal to 1, a new "list" column containing all comma separated "tags" (column names) should be created.

```
id  A   B   C
1   0   1   0
2   1   1   0
3   1   0   1
4   0   0   1
```

Desired result:

```
id  A   B   C   list
1   0   1   0   B
2   1   1   0   A, B
3   1   0   1   A, C
4   0   0   1   C
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option with `apply` from `base R`

```
df$new <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x==1]))
```

Here, we are creating a string column, but if the intention is to create a `list` column

```
df$new <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) names(x)[x==1])
```

Comment: Actually the code was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Now I am trying to add it as a dplyr code: `df %>% select(A, B, C) %>% apply(1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x==1]))` but was not able to create a new column...

Comment: @User This is not the best way of using a `base` solution, but this works and adds your desired column: ```df %>% mutate(col=apply(.[-1], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x==1])))```

Comment: @User You can also use `library(purrr);df %>% mutate(col = pmap_chr(select(., -id), ~ c(...) %>% {toString(names(.)[.==1])}))`

`

Comment: The second one (`df %>% mutate(col = pmap_chr(select(., -id), ~ c(...) %>% {toString(names(.)[.==1])}))`) is inverted (i.e., taking all the ones with 0 instead of 1)! But the first one worked fine, thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. I wanted to mark both answers - yours akrun and M-- as correct - but Stack Overflow only let me mark one as correct. So I will mark yours as correct as it is easier for understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Since question is tagged with `dplyr`, here's a solution using that and `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

```r
df1 %>% 
  gather(col, val, A:C) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(val==1) %>% 
  select(-val) %>% 
  nest(list = col) %>% 
  right_join(df1, .) %>% 
  arrange(id)
```

```r
#>   id A B C list
#> 1  1 0 1 0    B
#> 2  2 1 1 0 A, B
#> 3  3 1 0 1 A, C
#> 4  4 0 0 1    C
```

#### *Update:*

If you want the column to be class of `character`, then following works:

```r
df1 %>% 
  gather(col, val, A:C) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(val==1) %>% 
  select(-val) %>% 
  summarise_each(list(~paste(., collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  right_join(df1, .) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```r
#>      id A     B     C     col  
#>   <dbl> <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>
#> 1     1 0     1     0     B    
#> 2     2 1     1     0     A, B 
#> 3     3 1     0     1     A, C 
#> 4     4 0     0     1     C
```

Comment: I always prefer the dplyr solution. But if I run your code, I get the following class for the new generated list column: "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr". Would like to have it as character class.

Comment: @User that's a list of characters. Do you prefer to be a character variable? What is it now :`list("A" , "B")`. Do you want it to be `"A, B"`?

Comment: Exactly! Similar to this solution: `df$new <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x==1]))`. I tried to turn it into a dplyr solution: `df %>% select(A, B, C) %>% apply(1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x==1]))`, but was not able to create a new column.

Comment: @M-- If you want to use rowwise, another approach is `df1 %>% mutate(col = pmap_chr(select(., -id), ~ c(...) %>% toString(names(.)[.==1])))`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simple for loop based solution using base R

```
df[1,]<-c(0,1,0)
df[2,]<-c(1,1,0)
df[3,]<-c(1,0,1)
df[4,]<-c(0,0,1)

for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  x1<-which(df[i,]==1)
  y<-colnames(df)
  print(y[x1])
}
```

```
#output
[1] "B"
[1] "A" "B"
[1] "A" "C"
[1] "C"
```

Comment: The problem of this solution that it also takes the column names of a data frame and does not separate into comma separated character class column - each line is a vector.